# what function if i want to count spesific word that i found in one article

Tags: php, function

For example, if i have this article (string):

> > ...
>
> Inky is pretty unlike any other email app currently available on Linux – not just in looks but also in features.
>
> > For example, Inky scans your inbox and contacts during set-up to work
> >     out which messages are more likely to be ‘important’ to you, and which
> >     aren’t. The darker an ink drop next to a message the more important
> >     Inky considers it.
>
> ...

[source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/inky-pens-linux-support-on-roadmap]

And i want to count a spesific word. So, the result is:

Word:

Inky (3 words)

email (1 word)

Linux (1 word)

...

etc

What function in php should i use?

Comment: Is the data you want to count words in contained in a string or a file or...? Also, what do you mean by 'a specific word'? You only want to count one the occurrence of one word passed in as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $string = <<<_STRING_
  Inky is pretty unlike any other email app currently available on Linux – not just in looks but also in features.

  For example, Inky scans your inbox and contacts during set-up to work out which messages are more likely to be ‘important’ to you, and which aren’t. The darker an ink drop next to a message the more important Inky considers it.
_STRING_;
$word_count = str_word_count($string, 1);
$search_for = array('Inky', 'linux', 'email');
foreach ($search_for as $item) {
  $count[$item] = 0;
}

foreach ($word_count as $key => $word) {
  if (in_array($word, $search_for)) {
    $count[$word]++;
  }
}
print $count['Inky'];
print $count['linux'];
print $count['email'];
?>
```

Just a rough example but hopefully it will set you on the right path.

Comment: +1 Didn't know about the format parameter on str_word_count()

Comment: Yeah... Not one I use a whole lot, but obviously some people do (as in right now)... ;) @bob: I improved the answer a little bit too, because I think sometimes capitalization might have been an issue, and also so it requires less coding (in case you haven't seen the change yet).